# Binding Vue component data to external state

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue component that needs to be embedded into a large legacy (not Vue) system in several places. 
The component makes some AJAX requests and displays information based on an array of database record IDs, which it usually receives at page load time. The array is embedded directly into the page template by the server, and passed as props to the component, like so:

```
let config = {
  records: {{ template_code_outputting_array }},
  ...otherConfigOptions
}

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(ComponentName, {
    props: config
  })
})
```

My problem is that on one of the screens it needs to be embedded into, the database records can be selected dynamically by the user with a search-and-add type AJAX interface (rather than being pre-set at page load), so I need to keep the component in sync with the user's selection so it can be re-rendered as necessary.

I have a working solution but it's far from ideal; I'm currently directly calling a method on the component every time the user makes some change to their selection, passing the new selection so that the component can update its own internal copy:

```
app.$children[0].recordsChanged(newSelection)
```

But obviously this isn't reactive, and it feels kind of hacky. I feel like I shouldn't be directly addressing a component, and the function I'm calling is there solely for external use; nothing inside the component uses it.

I've tried binding values in *data* to global variables (which again isn't ideal but I don't have much choice) then adding a *watch* method to trigger a re-render on change. Obviously scalar values won't work as they'll be by value and not reference, but wrapping them in an object doesn't seem to work either. They bind fine and take the initial values provided, but updating the object (either directly mutating its values or replacing the object with a new one) doesn't seem to trigger the *watch* method or any reactivity.

Is there any best practice for doing this or is my current approach the best I can hope for?

Comment: Why wont you use a vue event bus? like `var bus = new Vue({})`. then you can do everywhere you want `bus.$emit("someEvent", {new: data})` and in your component do `bus.$on("someEvent", doSomething)`. make sure to assign the bus variable to the window

Comment: @AfikDeri That has actually helped a lot, so thank you. I've been able to export a function wrapping the emit so no-one making any changes to the external code will need any Vue knowledge. It would still be nice if I could make it totally reactive and avoid the function call altogether, but I'm starting to think there is no cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An event bus (as suggested by AfikDeri in the comments) is a good solution. It provides a straightforward interface.

Reactive-izing your data is also possible, [with some caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). An **Object** used to initialize a data item will itself be made reactive. If the things that change your array [do so in the approved ways](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats), you should see the changes inside your Vue.

```js
let stuff = [2, 3, 5];

const v = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    reactiveStuff: stuff
  },
  components: {
    myComponent: {
      props: ['arr'],
      template: '<div><div v-for="item in arr">{{item}}</div></div>'
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  stuff.push(7);
}, 1200);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<my-component id="app" :arr="reactiveStuff">
</my-component>
```

Comment: Roy, how can I replace/set/modify one of the values of ` stuff` array? I mean how can I override this `stuff[2] = 123` keeping reactivity?

Comment: @webprogrammer You need to use [`set` or `splice`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) so Vue notices the change to an array element.

Comment: Roy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727977/how-to-pass-vue-instance-to-external-script - I have created question about this here. I supposed that I need to pass vue instance to use it within extra script. Can I use `Vue.set()` instead of passing vue instance? Can you left me there some opinion? Thank you!

Comment: @webprogrammer Yes, you can use `Vue.set`.