# How to pass vue instance to external script?

Tags: vue.js, contenteditable

I have this declaration of `editor` in component vue file:

```
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            editor: new Editor({
                doc: this.value,
                vueInstance: this,
            }),
        }
    },
```

I am using `editor.doc` for generating template within contenteditable.

After each keydown event `editor.doc` should be changed and template should be updated. It means I need change `editor.doc` kepping reactivity within `Editor()` external script like this:

```
vueInstance.$set(this.doc, someKey, someValue);
```

. That is why I pass `vueInstance: this` to `Editor()`. But I get error after doing this.

I get these errors in google chrome :

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded 
TypeError: "t is undefined"
```

and I get these errors in firefox:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: t is undefined"
TypeError: "t is undefined"
```

How to properly modify `editor.doc` keeping reactivity? How to pass vue instance to external script if I need so?

Comment: It's not clear that Editor should be a `data` item. It seems like it should just be set up in the `created` hook.

Comment: @RoyJ, I call additional `this.editor.setRef(this.$refs.editorContainer);` within `mounted` hook. In such case `Editor` can be as `data` item. Also, It looks like I don't need using any `Vue.set()` methods inside `Editor` class. I don't know how but I can directly set value of `doc` properties and reactivity is keeping.